# how to open .swf file with adobe air

Tags: flash, air

I have an application that requires adobe air installed. After adobe air is installed, I can run the application by double-clicking a .swf file. Today I reinstalled the OS and adobe air. But now the .swf file seems not associated with adobe air. If I double-click the .swf file, the OS asks me to specify a program to open this kind of file. I could not find the air .exe program. How can I associate .swf file with adobe air?

Comment: If you have an AIR application then in your app's files there is an `.air` file that is the **actual** application. The swf is a supporting (contents) file. If you could open the SWF itself (without error pop-up) then it may not be an AIR application afterall. Maybe you need the Flash standalone player? See : https://blog.bannersnack.com/download-swf-player/ (or go to the official Flash Player site).

Answer (score 1):

Just publish the app to get a proper app file (.exe, .apk, .app). When publishing you need to create a self-signed certificate to sign your app and use it later on. Also you may want to embed the AIR runtime with your app, so the user doesn't have to search for it and download extra content manually.